# Как получить файл в php без долгого ожидания?

Tags: php, веб-сервер

Есть сервер A, на котором пользователь загружает страницу. При генерации этой страницы сервер должен запросить какие-то данные с сервера B, который может отвечать быстро (<0,5 сек), долго (от 0,5 до 5 сек), не ответить вовсе (>5 сек). Во втором случае нужно отдать пользователю страницу, но дождаться ответа и сохранить его в файл, в третьем случае просто отдать пользователю страницу с тем что сохранено локально. Как это реализовать правильно?

Лучшее что приходит в голову — потыкать сервер B через @file_get_contents, если что-то ответит — сохранить в файл, если не ответит — взять из файла, в который при прошлом удачном ответе сохранили. Но в этом случае страница не будет загружаться пока сервер A не выполнит весь запрос к B, а значит во второй ситуации мы будем до 5 секунд курить.

Answer (score 2):

Загружайте асинхронно сервером A с сервера B. Например, вызываете шел команду на получение файла в фоне. Или используйте очередь задач, что нить типа редиса. Общая схема такая будет

Clinet->Server A (отвечает клиенту страницей, на которой пишется текст заглушка и крутится аякс с переодическим запросом к серверу A (скрипт Б) - есть ли что показать и запрашивает фоном (на сервере фоном) скрипт (В) )

Скрипт Б - проверяет статус - есть ли файл (например через базу), если есть - отдаёт его, если нет, отдаёт - подождите ещё.

Скрипт В - запускается фоном на сервере, выставляет флаг что грузим, грузит файл с сервера Б,  и по завершению выставляет флаг - что всё отлично.

Схема примерно такая. Переодический запрос аяксом можно переделать на nodejs например, но тогда можно и весь проект на нём сделать :-)

Запуск фоном - это или exec если не ошибаюсь, или можно крон настроить слушать.